# Program that converts common measurements; using functions; when the user chooses a certain number

Tags: python, function

I am asked to convert feet to inches, yards to feet, miles to yards, and miles to feet and then print the output. When the user selects a menu option, then selects the number of feet, the function is supposed to calculate the assigned code assigned to it, return its value and print the result. I have a portion of the code below. I knew if I could not make it print the first set of code, then it would not print any of the other choices either. The error I get is on "if choice == 1:" The error says it's unreachable. Any help is appreciated.

```
choice = int(input("Please choose a menu option: "))
choice2 = int(input("Enter the number of feet: "))


def feet_to_inches(userFeet):
    inches = "userFeet / 1" * 12
    return inches

    if choice == 1:
        feet_to_inches = userFeet
        print(feet_to_inches)
```

Comment: Your `return` statement will end the function execution, why do you have that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unreachable because you are ending the function before it can reach the if statement with

```
return inches
```

instead, use that after your if statement is done

```
def feet_to_inches(userFeet):
    inches = "userFeet / 1" * 12

    if choice == 1:
        feet_to_inches = userFeet
        print(feet_to_inches)

    return inches
```